# OpenGL, building with Android NDK errors

Tags: android, c++, c, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm building a 3d model viewer app for Android. The displaying and viewing of the model is written in C++ through OpenGL and I'm using Android NDK to mesh this with the android app. When I attempt to deploy the application though, I get many errors that deal with OpenGL code, for example:

```
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/GLES2/gl2.h:501: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/GLES2/gl2.h:502: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/GLES2/gl2.h:503: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/GLES2/gl2.h:504: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/GLES2/gl2.h:505: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
```

And also:

```
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:66: error: 'glFrontFace' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:67: error: 'glClearStencil' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:68: error: 'glStencilMask' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:70: error: 'glClearColor' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:72: error: 'glClear' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:76: error: 'glBindVertexArrayOES' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:76: error: 'PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYOESPROC' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:76: error: expected ';' before 'eglGetProcAddress'
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:77: error: 'glGenVertexArraysOES' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:77: error: 'PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC' was not declared in this scope
/Users/Preddy/Downloads/9781119975915/SDK/_chapter3-2/Android//jni/../../../common/gfx.cpp:77: error: expected ';' before 'eglGetProcAddress'
```

I am obviously missing something in my setup here. I am using Sequoyah (for compiling and debugging native code) and NDK ver. r5b (because Sequoyah cannot recognize later versions). Any suggestions are welcomed, I'm beginning to despair.

EDIT:
Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := openal
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/openal/*.c)
SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(SRC_FILES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS = -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -mno-thumb
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O3 -mno-thumb
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE   := templateApp
LOCAL_CFLAGS   := -O3 -mno-thumb 
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/openal/
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/bullet/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/ttf/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/nvtristrip/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/png/*.c)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/zlib/*.c)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/detour/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/recast/*.cpp)
SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../common/vorbis/*.c)
SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC_FILES)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libopenal
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/armeabi
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz -lm -ldl -lGLESv2 -lEGL -llog -lopenal
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3 -mno-thumb -Wno-write-strings
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O3 -mno-thumb -Wno-write-strings
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Do you have LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2 -lEGL somewhere in your Android.mk?

Comment: hey thanks for the comment, yes I do, I'll edit to show the Android.mk file

Comment: Just to make sure, do you include gl2.h anywhere in your gfx.cpp along with egl.h?